# How to restrict default COD in magento to certain zip codes only?

Tags: php, magento, module, magento-1.7, payment

I am using Cash On Delivery Payment method in magento 1.7.0.2.

I need this payment option only for certain zip codes/pin codes.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in COD you have a function

```
public function isAvailable($quote = null)
```

in this before last line `return $checkResult->isAvailable;`

you place an if condition `if($checkResult->isAvailable)`  call

```
$this->isZipCodeallowedForCod($zipCode,$quote)
```

and in this function apply logic to get billing address zip code from quote object and checking with list of zipcodes allowed and setting flag.

Note : When modifying this do not modify core code use rewrite or override concept of Magento.

Answer (score 2):

**STEP 1**
Go To file

```
app\code\core\Mage\Payment\etc\system.xml
```

Line no Nearly `596` under the `<cashondelivery translate="label">` xml Node
 Add code

```
<pincode translate="label">
    <label>pincode</label>
    <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>63</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</pincode>
```

**STEP 2**
Go To File
    `app\code\core\Mage\Payment\Model\Method\Cashondelivery.php`

Add following Function in `Class Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cashondelivery` before closing tag }

```
/**
* Get All postcode allowed for COD cash on delivary module
* @return array
*/
 public function getCODPincodes(){
     $pincodes = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/cashondelivery/pincode');
     $results=explode(',',$pincodes);
     $postcodes=array();
     if(count($results)>0){
        foreach($results as $result){
            $postcodes[] = $result;
        }
     }
     return $postcodes;
 }
```

**STEP- 3**
Go To File
`app\code\core\Mage\Payment\Block\Form\Container.php`

Ad following Function in `Class Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container` before closing tag }

```
 /**
 * Chcek Payment Method is COD(cash on delivary) and Shiping Pin code is available in list
 * @return boolean
 */
 protected function checkmethodbypin($method){
    if($method->getCode() == "cashondelivery"){
        $shippingPincode = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('postcode');
        $pincodes= Mage::getModel('payment/method_cashondelivery')->getCODPincodes();
        if(in_array($shippingPincode, $pincodes)) return true ;else return false;
    }
 }
```

**Step 4**
 Go to File

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\payment\methods.phtml
```

Find code Near Line 43

```
<?php if(!$oneMethod): ?>
    <input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]"title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')"<?phpif($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
<?php else: ?>
    <span class="no-display"><input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio"name="payment[method]" checked="checked" class="radio" /></span>
    <?php $oneMethod = $_code; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?></div><div>
<?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?></label>
```

Replace with

```
<?php if(($_method->getCode() == "cashondelivery") && !$this->checkmethodbypin($_method)){?>
    <dt><label style="color:red">COD (Cash on Delivary) not available on this pin code</label></dt>
 <?php }else{?>
    <dt>
        <?php if(!$oneMethod): ?>
        <input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]"title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')"<?phpif($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
        <?php else: ?>
        <span class="no-display"><input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio"name="payment[method]" checked="checked" class="radio" /></span>
        <?php $oneMethod = $_code; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?> <?phpecho $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?></label>
    </dt>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Never modify core. Lesson #1 in Magento Development

Answer (score 1):

Open your app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\payment\methods.phtml file.

In this file you can get quote shipping address from quote object , just get zip codes from address and inside `foreach ($methods as $_method):` check your condition if zip code and `$_method->getCode();` match then return.
You can get method code here .

Answer (score 0):

I did the following

in
app\code\local\Mage\Payment\Model\Method\Cashondelivery.php

I added the following function

```
public function getCODPincodes(){
    $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    $query = "select pincode from `pincode`";
    $results = $write->fetchAll($query);
    foreach($results as $result){
        $postcodes[] = $result['pincode'];
    }
    return $postcodes;
}
```

and in app\code\local\Mage\Payment\Block\Form\Container.php

i added the following code under `protected function _canUseMethod($method){`...

after the following block

```
if((!empty($minTotal) && ($total < $minTotal)) || (!empty($maxTotal) && ($total > $maxTotal))) {
        return false;
    }
```

add

```
if($method->getCode() == "cashondelivery"){
        $postcodes = Mage::getModel('payment/method_cashondelivery')->getCODPincodes();
        $shippingPincode = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('postcode');
        if(!in_array($shippingPincode, $postcodes)){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Note:

> I have all the pincodes in a table called pincode.
>
> I will develop a small module on this as this is a quick fix for my requirement

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to edit the file /app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Cashondelivery.php

Open it and add the code below to the very end of the class (just before the last “}” in the file):

```
public function isAvailable($quote = null)
{
    if ($quote) {
        // Here is the list of restricted Zip Codes
        $restrictedZips = array(
            '85001',
            '87965'
        );
        $address = $quote->isVirtual() ? $quote->getBillingAddress() : $quote->getShippingAddress();
        $customerZip = $address->getPostcode();
        if (in_array($customerZip, $restrictedZips)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return parent::isAvailable($quote);
}
```